# Usage of “welches”

Tags: grammar, gender, interrogative

I came across the following sentence:

> Welches ist die zuständige Behörde?

I wondered why it is *welches* and not *welche* (using feminine for Behörde).

A quick search in Google seems to indicate that *welches* is correct (returns many many more results), but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both versions are possible, but they have different nuances.

> *Welche**s*** ist die zuständige Behörde?

The *welches* here is entirely generic. It can be substituted with everything, which is especially helpful if we don’t know what we are really asking for. It’s like saying ‘I know *someone* is the appropriate authority, but I have no clue who they actually are.’

> *Welche* ist die zuständige Behörde?

This is a modification of the first sentence but knowing what kind of a thing we are looking for, and implicitly expecting an answer that has feminine genus.

> *Welche Behörde* ist zuständig?

This sounds more like ‘we have a list of possible authorities; which one should I ask?’ It sounds a tad more closed to me than the open-ended *welches ist …*

Essentially, all three are understood and all three are more or less equally valid. More detail can be found on [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-welcher3.html).

Answer (score 0):

*Welche* would be correct here, too, though in this word ordering with a quite *literary* touch (and a slightly different meaning, see below). More common would be

> Welche Behörde ist zuständig?

as an alternative to

> Welches ist die zuständige Behörde?

I’d say, you could express the difference between the two in English by

> Which agency is authorized?

vs.

> Which agency is the authorized one?

So in the second expression (which for my non-native feeling is not as frequent in English as the German counterpart) you focus more on the fact that there is a finite set of agencies and you ask for the right one, while in the first it's more "open-ended".

“Welches ist die” expresses “Which is … the one”, but I’m not sure about the exact syntactic explanation for it.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible explanations:

1. "Welches" is used in the sense of "Was". An English equivalent would be:

> What is the competent agency?

Unlike in English, Germany does not make as sharp a distinction between "welches" and "was" as English makes between "which" and "what".

2. There was a sentence before that included several examples of agencies, and all of them were neuter. E.g. "Wir kennen das Ordnungsamt und das Bauamt. Welches ist die zuständige Behörde?"

(as a side note: Jurists differentiate Amt from Behörde. Everyday language does not.)